# Custom url scheme in salesforce android app

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am looking to implement a custom url scheme (e.g. myapp://) so that my android app can be opened on the browser and/or from an email link. I understand that there are a lot of answers here that point to intent filters in the AndroidManifest.xml as the answer, but I have not been able to get it to work. I am not sure how to get my app to detect those intent filters. If someone can help me on this, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: It's kinda sticky and documentation is sparse.  I don't have time to post an answer now, but I'll try to get one in later today.

Comment: that would be great. Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Try a tutorial like this one: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intentfilter
in the part where it says `<data android:scheme="http"/>` set it to `<data android:scheme="myapp"/>`

Then in the Activity you put this IntentFilter in, just go ahead and do a `getIntent().getData()` and that will give you the URI. Then you can process as you like. For example if you send `myapp://opencontact/joe_bob` you can pull out the parts and open your ContactProfileActivity or whatever and show the user Joe Bob...

Comment: Hi Salil, thanks for your response. I have the intent filter, but I am not sure how to detect the intent filter. I am working on a Salesforce Android app and dont know where to put in the code. I am relatively new to it, so a walkthrough sample would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this one will make more sense then: http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-using-intents-and-intent-filters-to-leverage-other-apps/